# German verb for 'binge-watch'

Tags: english-to-german, verb, single-word-request

I'm preparing for a speaking assessment and an example question is about TV. I wanted to say how I like to binge-watch (watching multiple episodes in fast succession) a TV series.

I've looked on the internet but I could only get the nouns *Binge-Watching* and *Komaglotzen*.

If there is a verb for it that'd be most helpful.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast The other question does not really address "binge-watch" in terms of watching a whole season at once. Just look at the answers. "Glotzen" is not the same as "binge-watching". The answers rather refer to excessive watching, but that isn't necessarily watching the same thing at once. Binging can be also just zapping for hours.

Comment: I can't think of an expression for it, you'd phrase it differently, and put the colloquialism in different parts ("Am Wochende habe habe ich mir die komplette alte "Raumschiff Enterprise" Serie reingezogen/angesehen/angeschaut" etc.) Details depend on context and the register used.

Comment: I'm not into the nomenclature, but "komaglotzen" *is* a verb, or is it?

Comment: I would try "endlos-glotzen" or "Nonstopp-glotzen".

Comment: I would advise against using words like "komaglotzen," "endlos-glotzen," "nonstopp-glotzen" or, as some other respondent suggested, "suchten" during a speaking assessment(!). I have never heard any of these expressions; they sound like they come straight from the mouth of a 14-year old trying to annoy his parents. If you used them in a casual conversation with me on the subway, let alone during a speaking assessment, you would probably make me laugh due to the clear break in register. (This effect may be on purpose, of course, but I felt you may want to be told about it. ;))

Answer (score 15):

I think the expression that's closest in meaning would be

> eine Serie/einen Film (am Stück) verschlingen

It is used in recent news reports about binge-watching as you can tell from [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=eine%20serie%20verschlingen&oq=eine%20serie%20verschlingen&aqs=chrome..69i57.4500j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Google search

Comment: Warum das downvote?

Answer (score 13):

I would say
"ich mache gerne einen Serienmarathon", "ich schaue mir am liebsten immer gleich mehrere Folgen hintereinander an" or "ich schaue gerne die ganze Staffel am Stück".

I have to disagree with Adrian. The Google link shows examples where "verschlingen" is used to mean that people anticipate the show and very much enjoy watching it, or that series are very popular and many people watch them. In this case they would mostly watch every episode right when it comes out rather then giving enough time to then binge-watch.

Comment: Agreed – it's not clear unless you include the "am Stück" (in one piece).

Comment: Du hast nicht mal die Google Ergebnisse gelesen. In dem dritten Treffer wird über die Netflix Studie berichtet : *Auf Basis der Daten vom 1. November 2016 bis 1. November 2017 wurden jeweils die zehn Serien ausgemacht, die wahlweise genossen oder **verschlungen** wurden. Als genossen gilt, wenn eine Serie **pro Tag** weniger als zwei Stunden gesehen wurde. Entsprechend hat man mit **über zwei Stunden** eine Serie eher **verschlungen***

Comment: @Adrian please remember that Google searches and their results are subjective to each user and can vary immensly.

Answer (score 10):

When talking with friends, I would use the verb "suchten", as in

> Letztes Wochenende wollte ich eigentlich produktiv sein, aber dann hab ich nur *black mirror* gesuchtet.

Note that this is very colloquial, I can't find it in Duden. I would say it carries a slight amount of self-irony / self-deprecation. I would not use it with older people or in more formal settings -- judging what is appropriate in the speaking assassment is up to you ;-)

Comment: Finde ich unpassend,weil "Sucht" ein ganze Ecke stärker ist.

Comment: @Robert: Im üblichen Sprachgebrauch ja, in der Wortschöpfung „suchten“ ist die Bedeutung meiner Erfahrung nach abgeschwächt.

Comment: I would also add "durchsuchten" to signify watching the whole season of the show. It is colloquial, but should be easy enough to understand, even if one has never heard of it.

Comment: For me, this seems to be a group-word, or some jouvenile slang. I never heard it in 45 years of active use of German. Of course, new words come up (welcome!), but perhaps this one is a little bit too sectoral?

Answer (score 1):

Also in use:

> sich an einem Wochenende die ganze Serie **reinziehen**

Note that *reinziehen* works with everything from the world of media, show business and entertainment that can be consumed, so:

> sich ein Buch reinziehen
>
> sich den ganzen Goethe reinziehen
>
> sich eine CD von John Clopper reinziehen
>
> sich die Briefe der Verflossenen reinziehen (rarely)
>
> sich "Vom Winde verweht" reinziehen

But again, this is very colloquial, and you should be sure you know where to use it. It is appropriate if you are 15 years old and speaking to your peers. Or, as always, if you are a standup comedian imitating a certain type of person, or otherwise searching comical effect.

Or in other-than-infinitive form:

> Ich habe mir im Urlaub den ganzen Lenin reingezogen.
>
> Ich zieh'  mir jetzt das "Wohltemperierte Klavier" rein.

Comment: Du kriegst meinen upvote für "Ich zieh' mir jetzt das "Wohltemperierte Klavier" rein."

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe auch "bingen" schon gesehen, wobei das wohl nicht sehr verbreited sein dürfte, oder sogar mit der verwendung der Suchmaschine "Bing" verwechselt werden könnte.

Comment: In Verbindung mit Netflix habe ich auch schon `bingen` gehört. Ich würde deshalb eher _noch nicht_ weit verbreited sagen. :)